# Assign path of all parents to "this" node in tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

For a given input of

```json
[
  { id: 1, path: 'foo/bar/1' },
  { id: 2, path: 'foo/bar/2' },
]
```

I produce a tree that looks like below which is a tree representation of each path split by `/`.

```json
{
    "path": "foo",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "bar",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 1,
                    "nestingLevel": 2
                },
                {
                    "path": "2",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 2,
                    "nestingLevel": 2
                }
            ],
            "nestingLevel": 1
        }
    ],
    "nestingLevel": 0
}
```

So far i have the below code that does the above:

```js
const inputArray = [
  { id: 1, path: 'foo/bar/1' },
  { id: 2, path: 'foo/bar/2' },
];

const result = [];
const level = { result };

// Produce the tree
for (p of inputArray) {
  let last;
  let { path, ...rest } = p;

  path.split('/').reduce((r, path, i, { length }) => {
    if (!r[path]) {
      r[path] = { result: [] };

      last = { path, children: r[path].result };

      r.result.push(last);
    }

    return r[path];
  }, level);
  Object.assign(last, rest);
}

// Walk the tree and assign nesting level (intended for UI stuff)
function traverse(obj, nestingLevel = 0) {
  if (obj !== null && typeof obj == 'object') {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      value.nestingLevel = nestingLevel;
      traverse(
        value,
        // don't increment level if it's we're going over children []
        typeof value == 'object' && !Array.isArray(value) ? nestingLevel + 1 : nestingLevel
      );
    });
  }
}

traverse(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0], null, 4));
```

What i want to do (and can't yet figure out how) is to have the full parent path (as `fullPath`) added to each node so that the output looks like:

```json
{
    "path": "foo",
    "fullPath": "foo",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "bar",
            "fullPath": "foo/bar",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "1",
                    "fullPath": "foo/bar/1",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 1,
                    "nestingLevel": 2
                },
                {
                    "path": "2",
                    "fullPath": "foo/bar/2",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 2,
                    "nestingLevel": 2
                }
            ],
            "nestingLevel": 1
        }
    ],
    "nestingLevel": 0
}
```

Anyone care to share their thoughts?

Comment: consider using Lodash.js and forget the pain !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your 'traverse()' function, and add the cumulative path. Everytime when you step down, add another part. Assign that in each object level.

Your traverse function cool be changed like this:

```
// Walk the tree and assign nesting level (intended for UI stuff)
function traverse(obj, nestingLevel = 0,fullp = "")
{
  if (obj !== null && typeof obj == 'object')
  {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      value.nestingLevel = nestingLevel;
      if(typeof value == 'object' && !Array.isArray(value))
        traverse(value,nestingLevel+1,fullp);
      else{
        fp = fullp + "/" + obj.path;
        obj.fullPath = fp;
        traverse(value,nestingLevel,fp);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then the result is this:

```
{
    "path": "foo",
    "children": [
        {
            "path": "bar",
            "children": [
                {
                    "path": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 1,
                    "nestingLevel": 2,
                    "fullPath": "/foo/bar/1"
                },
                {
                    "path": "2",
                    "children": [],
                    "id": 2,
                    "nestingLevel": 2,
                    "fullPath": "/foo/bar/2"
                }
            ],
            "nestingLevel": 1,
            "fullPath": "/foo/bar"
        }
    ],
    "nestingLevel": 0,
    "fullPath": "/foo"
}
```